# USB not recognized on startup

Tags: windows-7, usb

One of my USB ports were reporting not to recognize the mouse. The problem was solved by using an alternative port but then it started reporting the same issue. Now neither of them work several minutes after the Windows started and keep displaying the error untill it finally works. At this moment both of them are working perfectly fine!

How can I diagnose the causes of this problem?

Comment: Have you tried using a different mouse?  Perhaps the cable or connector are damaged...

Comment: As @Mokubai said try with another mouse or you can try to uninstall all USB ports from the device manger and restart the system and check it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try to check the mouse on another computer. Try to reinstall chipset drivers (motherboard) or USB driver's in particular. I think the problem may come from a computer power supply unit too.